# Problem on diagonals in a polygon

Tags: euclidean-geometry, polygons

Consider the polygon $P$ in the following picture which has sides drawn in black and internal diagonals drawn in red and blue. $P$ has 4 convex angles and 4 concave angles in alternating order as it's clear from the picture.

[image]

I'm trying to understand if it is possible to shorten one or more sides or blue diagonals of $P$ in a continuous process in such a way that both the following conditions are satisfied:

- by shortening said sides or blue diagonals of $P$ no other side or blue diagonal of $P$ gets longer
- by shortening said sides or blue diagonals of $P$ the lengths the two red diagonals remain constant

All my attempts at doing so failed, so I guess the answer is no, but I can't produce a proof.

Comment: How many sides does the polygon have?

Comment: I thought it was clear from the picture that the polygon has 8 sides, is it not?

Comment: It was not specified!

Comment: Can you change the concave angle to ~180 degrees? As long as the angle isn't 180, triangle inequality gives you a smaller side.

Comment: @LarryB no, as it is shown in the picture the poligon $P$ has 4 angles $<\pi$ and 4 angles $>\pi$, but I'm not sure I'm understanding what you are saying

Comment: Make the angles that are > $\pi$ closer to $\pi$, that'll reduce the length of the sides. Ah, but it will increase the lengths of the diagonals. Can you move line segments $d_1$ and $d_2$? Are they required to intersect?

Comment: I've got a partial answer. Consider the derivative of a function $f:\mathbb{R}^{2\cdot 8} \to \mathbb{R}^{12}$, with $8$ two-coordinate points mapping to the twelve distance functions; the two constant diagonals, the eight sides, and the two concave diagonals. Take the derivative matrix, and multiply it by an "epsilon vector" on an arbitrarily small sphere. Set the constant diagonals derivatives to zero. Then... there's a system of inequalities, and I don't know where to go from there. I do know that each point is involved in exactly three distance calculations.

Comment: Not sure I understand. Start with the longest side (upper right, nearly vertical) and label it $a$, and then clockwise through the remaining sides, labeling them $b,c,d,e,f,g$. You can shorten any of the pairs $(a,b),(c,d),(e,f),(g,h)$, (making the polygon "less concave") and get a new polygon with $d_1, d_2$ unchanged. BTW, I'm guessing the two conditions in the OP are alternatives (you can do one or the other to attempt to get a new polygon, but not both). Is this correct?

Comment: No, they are not alternatives, they are conditions which must be both respected. If it's not clear from the text I'll correct it

Comment: How can the second condition be satisfied if you shorten a diagonal?

Comment: I've been thinking about your question for a while, not being able to find anything better than moving one vertex at a time is not possible. May I ask you where does your question come from?

Comment: I had an idea for a proof, but it doesn't work for the edit necessarily.

Do we not care about the diagonals from the endpoints of $d_1$ to the endpoints of $d_2$? Also, are we assuming that the four points not on $d_1$ or $d_2$ are positioned so that all the blue diagonals are contained in the interior of the polygon?

Comment: Also, are we only looking for $P'$ that can be obtained from $P$ through a continuous process of shortening sides, or are we looking for any $P'$ that has all the properties, even if it cannot be obtained by a continuous process of shortening sides?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is: We can't make another polygon like that, and I have too much free time on my hands. The slightly longer answer is that we can take the derivative of a function from points to distances. Using linear programming, we show that we can't have all the partial distances be non-positive, which means the can't be all non-increasing; this is exactly the condition that no side or blue diagonal may get longer.

---

Let $P$ be a polygon defined by this ordered list of points $A, a, B, b, C, c, D, d$. Upper-case-letter points are the "outer" points, lower-case-letter points are the "inner" points.

Suppose we map eight arbitrary two-coordinate points to the sixteen distances of the sides and diagonals. (I will be ignoring those eight diagonals between outer and non-contiguous inner points, because we're able to solve this problem without them.) Let $\mu$ be our distance function $\mu : \mathbb{R}^{16} \to \mathbb{R}^{16}$, such that:

- $\mu_1$: Distance from $A$ to $C$.
- $\mu_2$: Distance from $B$ to $D$.
- $\mu_3$: Distance from $A$ to $a$.
- $\mu_4$: Distance from $a$ to $B$.
- $\mu_5$: Distance from $B$ to $b$.
- $\mu_6$: Distance from $b$ to $C$.
- $\mu_7$: Distance from $C$ to $c$.
- $\mu_8$: Distance from $c$ to $D$.
- $\mu_9$: Distance from $D$ to $d$.
- $\mu_{10}$: Distance from $d$ to $A$.
- $\mu_{11}$: Distance from $a$ to $c$.
- $\mu_{12}$: Distance from $b$ to $d$.
- $\mu_{13}$: Distance from $a$ to $b$.
- $\mu_{14}$: Distance from $a$ to $d$.
- $\mu_{15}$: Distance from $b$ to $c$.
- $\mu_{16}$: Distance from $c$ to $d$.

Here are the constant cross-diagonals and side distances.

[image: distances 1 through 10, and points labeled]

And here are the inner-point diagonals that we are modeling.

[image: distances 11 through 16, and points labeled]

Derive the equation, and you get the [Jacobian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobian_matrix_and_determinant). We're gonna look at the derivative, but divided, since we only care about positive and negative derivative. It'll also make life easier when we go to solve this thing.

$$D\mu/2 = \left[\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial A_x}\ \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial A_y}\frac{\partial \mu}{\partial a_x}\ \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial a_y} \cdots \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial d_x}\ \frac{\partial \mu}{\partial d_y}\right]$$

Each of those $\partial\mu$ derivatives is actually a column.

For the sake of a proper derivative, I'm going to insert a variable $t$; you can intuitively think of this as time if you want, and the polygon like it's sorta moving. Whatever. It's just there to make things more formal. We want $\frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial t},$ dependent on some "movement derivatives" $\frac{\partial Point_c}{\partial t}$, like we're moving the point around. We get to choose the movement derivatives, and our goal is to choose them so that the distances either stay equal or decrease as we move our points. From the derivative equation, we know that:

$$\frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial t} = \frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial A_x}\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial t} + \cdots \frac{\partial \mu_i}{\partial d_y}\frac{\partial d_y}{\partial t}$$

So it's really like multiplying our matrix by a variable vector. Turns out, the matrix is pretty sparse.

What does each of these listings look like? For instance, in $\mu_1$, we get this equation:

$$\frac{\partial \mu_1}{\partial t} = (A_x - C_x)\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial t} + (A_y - C_y)\frac{\partial A_y}{\partial t} + (C_x - A_x)\frac{\partial C_x}{\partial t} + (C_y - A_y)\frac{\partial C_y}{\partial t}$$

---

At this point, I think it's a good idea to define our particular polygon. I found that these points describe the polygon well: $[(29, 51), (44, 127) (0, 218) ,(86, 185) ,(197, 282 ),(170, 169),(212, 0),(113, 59)]$. Remember, these are for the points $A, a, B, b, C, c, D, d$. I have a link below to plot this polygon, and you can check that it correctly "looks like" the original polygon in this problem, or is at least some acceptable approximation.

Given these polygon points, we can substitute actual numbers in the derivative now. Then we get:

$$\frac{\partial \mu_1}{\partial t} = -168\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial t} -231\frac{\partial A_y}{\partial t} + 168\frac{\partial C_x}{\partial t} + 231\frac{\partial C_y}{\partial t}$$

Hey, this looks like a linear equation! In that case, let `Ax` stand for $\frac{\partial A_x}{\partial t}$ in the following code listing.

```
max: Ax - ax + Ay - ay + Bx - bx + By - by + Cx - cx + Cy - cy + Dx - dx + Dy - dy;

r_Ax: Ax = 0;
r_Ay: Ay = 0;
r_Cx: Cx = 0;
r_Cy: Cy = 0;
r_1: -168 Ax -231 Ay +168 Cx +231 Cy = 0;
r_2: -212 Bx +218 By +212 Dx -218 Dy = 0;
r_3: -15 Ax -76 Ay +15 ax +76 ay <= 0;
r_4: +44 ax -91 ay -44 Bx +91 By <= 0;
r_5: -86 Bx +33 By +86 bx -33 by <= 0;
r_6: -111 bx -97 by +111 Cx +97 Cy <= 0;
r_7: +27 Cx +113 Cy -27 cx -113 cy <= 0;
r_8: -42 cx +169 cy +42 Dx -169 Dy <= 0;
r_9: +99 Dx -59 Dy -99 dx +59 dy <= 0;
r_10: +84 dx +8 dy -84 Ax -8 Ay <= 0;
r_11: -126 ax -42 ay +126 cx +42 cy <= 0;
r_12: -27 bx +126 by +27 dx -126 dy <= 0;
r_13: -42 ax -58 ay +42 bx +58 by <= 0;
r_14: -69 ax +68 ay +69 dx -68 dy <= 0;
r_15: -84 bx +16 by +84 cx -16 cy <= 0;
r_16: +57 cx +110 cy -57 dx -110 dy <= 0;
free Ax, Ay, Bx, By, Cx, Cy, Dx, Dy, ax, ay, bx, by, cx, cy, dx, dy;
```

This is the [LP File format](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/lp-format.htm) for the system of linear equalities that we're trying to solve. A couple things to note here:

- **Why are the derivatives for the points $A$ and $C$ set to $0$?** When I was running the `lp_solver`, I noticed it tended to give solutions that were just the original polygon, but translated or rotated. Without loss of generality, we can fix one of the constant diagonals in place. I chose the $AC$ diagonal.
- **Why are the other equations equal to zero?** Constant derivative means the equation doesn't move. We wanted to keep those diagonals constant, so we set those derivatives to zero.
- **What about the other inequalities?** We wanted non-increasing distances, whether they were sides or diagonals. That means their derivatives should be less than or equal to zero.
- **Why is everything listed as `free` at the bottom?** In the `lp_solver` program, variables not listed as `free` will take on non-negative values. Conversely, `free` variables take on all possible real values, including negative values. You can read more [here](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/free.htm).

Using the [`lp_solver` program](http://lpsolve.sourceforge.net/5.5/), punch that file in as input. You'll get zero for everything; none of the points can move. Replace the objective function with `max: bx` or `min: bx`. You'll get zero, meaning that zero is the only solution. In other words, if you try any other points, you'll break one of our linear programming constraints.

---

Suppose we only took the first twelve distance equations, that is, only the cross diagonals for the inner points. In that case, we do get a solution. It's unbounded, so take an inequality like this:

`r_100: Ax - ax + Ay - ay + Bx - bx + By - by + Cx - cx + Cy - cy + Dx - dx + Dy - dy <= 50;`

and append it at the end of the lp file listing. When we run the lp_solver program, we get a solution vector for our partial derivatives, which when added to the original points produces this sequence of points: $[(29, 51),(41.71038, 127.451899),(14.5611, 226.59952),(93.82524, 176.04534),(197, 282),(167.6759, 169.555315),(221.24608, 3.43074),(113.992273, 48.5811)]$. Compare that shape with our original shape by going [here](http://gojs.net/latest/extensions/PolygonDrawing.html). Copy/paste the text below and click "Load" to see the shapes. The new shape is on the left in red, the old shape is on the right in yellow.

```
{ "position": "0 0",
  "model": { "class": "go.GraphLinksModel",
  "nodeDataArray": [ 
{"fill":"yellow", "stroke":"blue", "strokeWidth":3, "category":"PolygonDrawing", "key":-2, "geo":"F M29 51 L44 127 L0 218 L86 185 L197 282 L170 169 L212 0 L113 59z", "loc":"532.25 247.25"},
{"fill":"red", "stroke":"green", "strokeWidth":3, "loc":"226 188", "category":"PolygonDrawing", "geo":"F M29 51 L41.71038 127.451899 L14.5611 226.59952 L93.82524 176.04534 L197 282 L167.6759 169.555315 L221.24608 3.43074 L113.992273 48.5811z", "key":-1}
 ],
  "linkDataArray": []} }
```

I've taken the coordinates and compared the difference between the distances for the two. Turns out, it's not exactly correct; it deviates from the original polygon by about three units. The largest deviations are between $a$ and $B$ (distance $101.0791769$ units in the original, compared with $102.7975396$ in the new one) and $B$ and $b$ (distance $92.11405973$ in the original polygon, compared with $94.01345119$ in the new one). I would chalk this up to numerical stability problems.

---

A couple questions remain:

- **What if I want to try a different polygon?** It's very simple. You can substitute the difference in the points' coordinates for any set of point coordinates. Then run any linear programming solver you like, and see what pops out. I would guess, for this configuration, it will probably be zero regardless of the objective function.
- **Can you solve this for a generic polygon that "looks like" the one in the statement?** The question asks to solve for *this* polygon $P$, not necessarily for any polygon $P$ that looks like it. Then again, giving a particular instance and solving it is not really in the spirit of the question. What can we do to make the sixteen point coordinates into free variables? The best I've come up with, for now, is considering all the left-of relations. Given three points $A, B, C$, the point $C$ is left of the line $AB$ if $A_xB_y + B_xC_y + C_xA_y - A_xC_y - C_xB_y - B_xA_y < 0$. Unfortunately, that's not a linear inequality.

Comment: First of all, thank you very much for all the effort you put in your answer. Just a note: in the beginning you wrote "we show that we can't have all the partial derivatives of distances be positive, which means they can't all be increasing" which doesn't make much sense to me, but then you imposed all the derivatives to be $<=0$, to which I agree. My knowledge in coding is very limited, I just know some basics of Mathematica, so I'll try to solve this system there.

Comment: Cool use of linear programming

Comment: @LarryB Just another comment: your approach relies on the knowledge of the exact coordinates of the vertexes of the polygon $P$. Do you think that it could be adapted in case the coordinates of the points are not known exactly? For example for any polygon "shaped like $P$" i.e. which has 4 convex angles and 4 concave angles in alternating order?

Comment: @user372511, to your first comment: that is a typo, I meant to say "we can't have all the partial distances be non-positive, which means the can't be all non-increasing", which is related to your condition that no side or blue diagonal get longer. I will edit that. To your second comment: I dunno. You could certainly use the derivative to plug in other coordinates, and then solve the LP for those. In my original comment to your question, I tried the approach of leaving the coordinates undefined. I guess, since it's an arrangement of points, I could try to impose "left-of" inequalities...

Comment: @LarryB. If you're interested I've asked another question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2281987/polygons-with-2-diagonals-of-fixed-length-part-two in which I try to develop your reasoning in case of a non fixed polygon

Answer (score 1):

This a classical engineering problem, that falls under the subject of  [Static Analysis of Trusses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truss),
as well as under that of [Kinematic Chains](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kinematic_chain).
You are probably not familiar with such discipline, and there is no space here to resume its basis.
However, since everybody has common experience of trusses and kinematic chains, I will cite here some facts that should sound
"plausible", while referencing to specialized documentation for a rigourous treatment.

[image: Hinged_Truss_2]

The figure above translates the problem you proposed in the engineering language.

The black and red segments are stiff rods (elements) and the circles represents pin joints (nodes).
Being stiff, all the elements are supposed not to change in length, and can only rotate 
around the joints. Note that at the points where the diagonal elements cross
there is no bound, meaning that the elements can freely slide over each other.

Now, a rigid body in the plane has three degre of freedom to move: two for translation
and one for rotation.
To null them and "keep the truss on the drawing sheet" it is customary to fix the $(x,y)$ position 
of one node (here $A$) and  give another (suitably chosed) only the fredom to move horizontally (here $C$).
In this way the whole truss can only have "internal" movements and not "as a whole".

One of the major scopes of the *Static Analysis* is to determine infact if the truss can have or not
such "internal movements". If it has, it will be unstable, and under a minimal load it will collapse, in the sense
that it will change its shape macroscopically. If it has not, then it may be *Isostatic* or *OverConstrained*.
And this distinction is very important in *Construction Design*.

Your question practically translates to ask whether the truss is underconstrained or not.

A result of *Static Analysis*, well known to all engineers, says that a necessary condition for the system
to be underconstrained is that
$$ 
m < 2n - 3 
$$
(if $m=2n-3$ it is isostatic, and overdetermined if $m>2n-3$)
where $m$ is the number of elements and $n$ the numbers of nodes (pin joints).
The results comes from analyzing the degrees of freedom of the various members and the degrees
reduced by the constraints.

Your "truss" gives $m=10<2n-3=13$, and so it is heavily undetermined, having $3$ degrees of freedom
unrestrained.
Thus it can move without changing the length of any member, and since shortening consumes 1 degree
of movement, sure you can short any segment even without changing the length of the other $9$.
Clearly, the amount of movement or shortening is limited to a certain extent.

The picture below provides an example

[image: Hinged_Truss_2_012]

*---  Addendum   ----*

Finally, after the clearing got from the comments and the re-editing of the post, the truss has become highly *Hyperstatic*.
To solve the problem in this case we can refer to a truss whose members are stiff vs. elongation
and soft vs. compression,  except only the diagonals $AE$ and $GC$ which are stiff  in both directions.
A sort of a truss made by wires around the two main diagonal rods.

If such a truss turns out to be stable, then it means that you cannot shorten a side without stretching some other.

But now the truss is quite complicated to be solved "by hand", and its non-linear stiffness complicates the analysis
(a director's chair is not a proper truss).

[image: Hinged_Truss_3]

If we move the sliding bound to $E$, we get a vertical stiff rod ($GC$) connected at both ends
by wires stranding from the fix nodes, and these strands are then tightly knotted somewhere in between in all
directions (the other connections are not shown to reduce cluttering).
Common experience suggests that it should be sufficient to secure the vertical rod 
(unless of extreme configurations).
But how to provide mathematical evidence of that is out of my reach, at present.

Comment: This is all great stuff, but I don’t think you’ve modeled the original question. The first condition desired by the OP is that “by shortening said sides or diagonals of P no other side or diagonal of P gets longer.” Your truss only includes two of the diagonals, but there are others. (I’m not sure whether the OP is considering all of them, but I think s/he is considering at least more than the two shown in the picture.)

Comment: @GCab thank you for your answer, but it seems wrong to me. Maybe you don't have understood correctly the question: I've clearly written that no diagonal of $P$ can get longer, but it doesn't seem like you have considered this condition. For this reason also the two pictures "movement without change in length" and "AB shortened" are wrong. Maybe there's a way to adapt the static analysis of trusses to consider also this conditions on the diagonals?

Comment: @user372511: yes, of course, static analysis of trusses applies to "any" configuration, but it needs some engineering expertise. If you add diagonals $FB$, $HD$, you just increase $m$ by $2$ and the truss is still underdetermined by $1$ degree.  However, if you add, e.g., $EG$ than $EF$ and $FG$ are *redundant* and can be cancelled/treated separately from the whole. If I have  time I will supplement my answer accordingly.

Comment: @SteveKass: well I was actually unsure about the meaning to assign to "Diagonals". However Static Analysis and the simple condition on No. of members and nodes applies in general, with the cautions advised in my comment above. Note that in the essence, the Truss configuration is translated into a matrix (*redundant -> rank*), which together with the loads configuration is used for further FEM /mechanism analysis.

Comment: @user372511: N.B. " ... add $EG $ ... " (if you do not add also $FB$)

Comment: @GCab ok thank you, but do you understand that you have to consider also $all$ the lengths of all the diagonals of the polygon? by that I mean all the following: $GD,GB,FH,FB,FD,EH,EB,DH,DB,BH,CF,CH,AF,HB,HD,HE$. All the lengths of all these diagonals can decrease but not increase. I thought it was clear from my question.

Comment: So, can we call it in a few words "totally INTERNALLY connected" (meaning no $EC$ etc.)?

Comment: @GCab I've updated the picture in my question, now it must be clear. To answer your question: yes, if by "totally internally connected" you mean that the red diagonals can not change their lengths and the blue diagonals can only maintain or decrease their lengths

Comment: Thank you, but it's exactly that "common experience suggests.." that I'd like to formalize