# Polygons with 2 diagonals of fixed length (part two)

Tags: inequality, euclidean-geometry, linear-programming, polygons

In this question of mine

[Polygons with two diagonals of fixed length](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2265718/polygons-with-two-diagonals-of-fixed-length)

I've presented the following particular polygon $P$

[image]

and I've asked the following question: is it possible to shorten one or more sides or blue diagonals of $P$ in a continuous process in such a way that both the following conditions are satisfied:

- by shortening said sides or blue diagonals of PP no other side or blue diagonal of $P$ gets longer
- by shortening said sides or blue diagonals of $P$ the lengths the two red diagonals remain constant

User Larry B. proved that the answer is "no" using a linear system of inequalities concerning the lengths of sides and diagonals.

**Now I want to understand if the same is true for any polygon which "looks as $P$"**: by that I mean any polygon with 8 vertexes and with 4 convex angles and 4 concave angles in alternating order and such that the two red diagonals stay inside the polygon. Clearly this will make things more complicated than in my previous question..

Answer (score 1):

In here i am including the assumptions of the problem, please got me corrected if i am failing here?:

- Graph with 8 nodes, 4 outer and 4 inner,
- Red links are fixed,
- Blue and Black links can decrease in magnitude, can not increase,
- Red and Blue links are interior to the shape (that is the only difference between blue and black links?).

Lets add the following less trivial assumptions:

- Each node must have at least 3 links and/or constraints,
- a total of 2N degrees of freedoms must be fixed,
- 2 constraints must be added for fixing the (2D) position,
- 1 constraint must be added for fixing the (2D-1) rotation,
- hence a total of 2N-3=13 constraints shall be included.

**Optimization through Calculus of Variations - Karush Kuhn Tucker**

Each virtual displacement over any node should not increase any node, respecting all the constraints:

$$
J=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{j in I(i)} d_{ij}^2
$$

Where $d_i$ is the distance (strength) of every link measured from the $x_i$ node onto every other node, where the $i(j)$ overloaded notation is the $j$th node connected to $i$, $I$ is the set of all indexes connected to the $i$ node, and $f$ Is the current distance constraint.

$$
F_{ij}=f_{ij}-d_{ij}^2 \ge 0, i=1:N, j \ \text{in} \ I(i)
$$

The constraints on the red links are expressed as:

$$
G_{kj}=d_{kj}-g_{kj}=0, (k,k(j)) \ \text{is red}
$$

Thus the optimal conditions came from the Karush Kuhn Tucker (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karush–Kuhn–Tucker_conditions) conditions which are no more than the Euler Lagrange multiplier extended for the constrained case.

These conditions seek for the optimal solution of every term on $F$ and every term on $G$, through the solution of the generalized gradient $\nabla$ form expressions - **the KKT conditions**:

$$
\nabla J_i+ \sum_{ij} \mu_{ij} \nabla F_{ij}+ \sum_{kj} \lambda_{kj} \nabla G_{kj}=0
$$

The $\mu_{ij}\ge 0$ and $\lambda_{kj}$ are the KKT multipliers of the problem. Note that the gradients express the direction of increase of the distance, and we are interested in the opposite of the gradient for minimizing them.

All the previous is only written as an introduction for the KKT, quite standard without the artificial indexes for the nodes included:

$$
\nabla J_j+ \sum_{j} \mu_{j} \nabla F_{j}+ \sum_{j} \lambda_{j} \nabla G_{j}
$$

This is simply the sum of each gradient of the strength functionals for each link, included the constraints, when applicable (when there is no red link attached, $\lambda_j$=0).

Also, the gradients of the expressions are nothing more than the directions vectors of the links, toward the increase direction of the length: the line itself.

For the given geometry, it is straightforward to prove that it is always possible to find multipliers for making the satellite expression equal to zero.

For the outer nodes, it is always possible to find positive numbers satisfying the condition. Note the arrangement of the expression for maintaining all multipliers positive. Hence the black links and the red must not be $/pi$ or 0. This holds because the red direction is always between the black directions -inside the polygon:

$$
\mu_{i1}\nabla F_{i1}+\mu_{i2}\nabla F_{i2}=\lambda_i\nabla G_i, i=1:4
$$

For the inner nodes, the expression is similar, though including the fact that the third direction will always be LD with the previous. The arrange in here again take into account the geometry positioning a pair of gradients at the opposite side of the node. Hence again, the angle between the black links $acos(\nabla F_{i1},\nabla F_{i2})$ must not be $\pi$ or 0. It is always possible to find the positive directions, because there is always a node in the polygon which have an angle greater than $pi/2$, with both black rods at the node. If not, then the polygon is flat, and several links passes through the indicated node, which introduces a degeneracy.
Thus, for the inner nodes, we can always find three links and positive multipliers such that all directions turns into a zero sum, satisfying again the KKT condition:

$$
\mu_{i1}\nabla F_{i1}+\mu_{i2}\nabla F_{i2}+\mu_{i3}\nabla F_{i3}, i=1:4
$$

This proves that for the given geometry and constraints, it is not possible to minimize the functional of distances, and in particular, not any single distance.

Comment: Yes, i will check the signs for fitting everything into the minimization problem. The final key argument is that the gradients must all compensate, and under the conditions given, it is not possible to decrease any of them. The outers because the red constraints make that impossible, the inners because the blacks opposite "some" blue. The geometry always make that possible to find a linear combination of positive numbers making that. The detailed step by step proof of that geometric conditions should be proved, and an image of the gradients vectors cancelling each other could be added....

Comment: ... though the key points was expressed.

Comment: Thank you, just one last comment, then I'll wait for your edits: what you are trying to prove is that the only point of $\mathbb{R}^{16}$ which minimizes all $J_i$ is the point of the coordinates of the original polygon, right?

Comment: No, we are always on $\mathbb{R}^2$, that is important. All the gradients are on the (x,y) plane, thus the minimization problem can be realized just as a geometric problem. The given KKT expression is solely for stating that the gradients must compensate, as in a free body diagram. That is all. The rest is checking that the lines cannot stretch because this or that.

Comment: I dont have majors edits for the question, actually. Perhaps i could do later, but just for beauty :).

Comment: For the $x_i$ point, the gradient is $[u_i-u_j, v_i-v_j]$, the partial derivatives $d/du_i, d/dv_i$ as per the definition of gradient; the direction vector of the links in $\mathbb{R}^2$, a direction pointing from $x_j$ towards $x_i$, hence pointing towards the maximum increase of the distance: the straigh line.

Comment: Hence i am losting my time here in making a proof if there is not previous knowledge for understanding the basics behind the proof. KKT is supposed to be perfectly known beforehand.

Comment: I've reduced my questions to 3:
1) How do you define the functions $F_{ij}$? Are they $F_{ij}:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $F_{ij}(u,v):=1/2((u-u_i)^2+(v-v_i)^2)-f_{ij}$, where $f_{ij}$  is half the square distance between the i-th and j-th vertex in the original polygon?
2) Defining all functions on $\mathbb{R}^2$ aren't you just trying to move one vertex at a time?
3) Why are you imposing both $\nabla J_i$ and $\sum_j\mu_j\nabla F_j+\sum_j\lambda_j\nabla G_j$ to be zero? The stationary KKT condition is $\nabla J_i+\sum_j\mu_j\nabla F_j+\sum_j\lambda_j\nabla G_j=0$

Comment: Here are the answers: 1) The main function to be minimized, J, is the sum of the distances, the main inequality constraints F, are the distances being greater than the current distances, and the main equality constraints G, are the distances on the red links. All these functions with 2N variables.

Comment: 2) When we started talking about variational principle, and virtual displacements, the key fundamental is moving one degree of freedom as a time. That is the base of all of these method. Then the lagrangian and kkt and all these are deduced........

Comment: Because we are *minimizing", we sum all the gradients, and that sum shall be zero. That is the same for the lagrangian, and the same for the unconstrained basics. I think there is a typo in the answer, it shall read "plus".

Comment: Still, this is not the core part of the writing, which you will lost if never worked with those expressions before. And which i suggest youto ask for some instructor in your college. The gradients and all functions are in 2N-D BUT the geometric interpretation is still in 2D. So you dont have to be submerged in the algebra. You just take the distances and compute the gradients by handand you are ready to solve your problem. Ask your instructor about this interpretation, which holds for most of the geometrical like problems

Comment: I told you, i am moving one vertex at a time, actually, one DOF at a time. IF not, the gradient cannot be computed, it should be a total derivative. Gradients are partial derivatives... Do you know gradients and vectorial calculus?, If you are lost in here, you need previous preparation for understanding the proof. But still can get the concept of optimizing going through the minimal descent, which is actually the idea.

Comment: The geometrical approach is probably the same you are figuring out now, On the outers, there are circles defining the gradient directions, and these cannot be broken, because of their direction. That is the meaning when i am saying there is a linear combination with positive constants (linear algebra, another course you would require). On the inner, you canot move to any side because every link is "tieing" you. Again, this is justified through the linear combination fact. So you cannot move anywhere, vertex-wise. And fixing the rotations and translations, you finally got frozen.

Comment: I suggest you to start with simpler geometries, if possible got some solver and find the optimal solutions. Also get the truss approach, which is in some ways the same. Also got the basics proofs for the Lagrangian optimization, but try to reach the sum of gradients form, as we already did in here. With all that functional knowledge you would be equipped with several tools for facing almost any other problem you can found.

Comment: As you said, just pick a solver, and start moving one vertex at a time, blind and brute forcedly. You will realize there are some directions in which you can, and other in which you cannot. That is basically a Newton Raphson, rediscovered. You will converge to a Star shaped figure after some iterations!, and you will realize this shape is the optimal, actually, a box slightly looking as a Star. You dont need huge code in there, just a for cycle and little changes in the coordinates, when allowed by your constraints.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Note this answer is invalid. Included here only for reference.

This problem is trivially solved through the Truss approach, as indicated in one of the answers of the original question. This problem is repetitive in systems.

This kind of graphs is nothing more than a certain number of nodes, each one with 2 degrees of freedom (DOF), all of which must be solved.

- The polygon has N=8 vertex, and we are in a 2D space, hence we have 2*N DOF available,
- For limit the traslation, we must set one node as the origin (0,0), fixing 2 DOF. In R dimensions, we fix R DOF by doing this,
- For limit the rotation, we must restrict the rotation of the whole graph. Hence the rotation of the set is only one number, fixing thus 1 DOF. In R dimensions, rotations have R-1 parameters (DOFs).
- Hence, we have 2N-3=13 DOFs remaining. Hence, the topology of the graph - that is, the relation between the nodes - must add the required equations for defining the system.
- There are 8 black bars. Assume their distance fixed and we fix 1 new DOF per each node, fixing 8 DOFs new in total,
- There are 2 red bars, restricting 1 new DOF at 2 nodes, fixing 2 new DOFs in total,
- Now add 3 blue bars, restricting 1 new DOFs at 3 additional nodes not connected by the previous bars, fixing 3 new DOFs in total.

With that, all the 2N DOFs of the system got well constrained, and the quadratic system is well determined. Note that the way we added the constraints is the way we added the equations of the quadratic system, for not adding a degeneracy -i.e. adding all the diagonals in a single node, and letting nodes disconnected.

Thus, we only have to check if the quadratic matrix is diagonalizable.

Geometrically in 2D, it is equivalent to say that each node or shape is connected to a triangular shape which "stiff" them. In N dimensions this is equivalent to say that each node or shape is connected to a N-simplex shape (tetrahedrons).

Fixing 3 blue diagonals at any part of the graph will make the system of equation well-defined. Adding more than 3 diagonals will make the system over-determined, that is, the additional diagonals are linearly dependent constraints from the above.

**If we allow** the distance to be altered according some function of the metric: i.e. f(x)=kx^2, the quadratic system add an additional term.

Comment: I will add the equations as soon as i can.

Comment: Then, it is impossible to reduce any blue or black line, keeping the red diagonals fixed. There is a simple argument given the geometry that makes any virtual diaplacement under a calculation of variations constrained in each direction: 1. Because the fixed red diagonals and the black bars are inside the outer vertexs, and covers the constraint of the red diaplacement and the gradient descent of the black bars, and 2. Because the blue and black bars gradient descents cover all directions for the inner vertexs. I will modify the new answer, as proof for a general case.

Comment: This can be generalized to higher sizes and dimensions too, providing in the ND case there should be a proper number of bars and diagonals for properly cover each direction.